# Is it possible for two child-classes to work together

Tags: oop, inheritance, uml, class-diagram, class-design

I have one base-class named Product. Classes "Drink" and "Pizza" are subclasses that inherit from the "Product" class.
I also have a class named "Ingredient" Which is a part of the Pizza class, so the Pizza class should have an instance (a list) of the Ingredient class.

My question is:
Since the Ingredient has the same properties like all the other "Products", can it also inherit from the "Product" class while working together with the "Pizza" subclass?

[image: Click here to see my current UML Design]

Comment: If the `Ingredient` class extends the core functionality (same properties, same method signatures, etc) as specified by the Product class it should inherit from `Product`. However if `Product`s have/define members that do not represent an Ingredient (for example if Product had a method called `SellToCustomer()` which you don't want to apply to a Pizza Ingredient) then the `Ingredient` class should not inherit from `Product`. Whether or not  `Pizza` and `Ingredient` keep References of each other and "work together" is a completely different thing.

Comment: Do what makes more sense for you. Can an ingredient be considered as a product in your business context? If so, then you would want it to be a product as well.

Comment: Maybe you can create an Item and both Product and Ingredient/Material inherit from it where as a Product can be sold while an Ingredient/Material is used to create a Product. Whatever the case, you should do what makes sense. Also don't over engineer if you don't foresee a reasonable benefit.

Comment: This seem like a typical example when teaching Object Orientation. But often inheritance is not the best way to do it. Eric lipperts articles on [wizards and warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) might be a long but useful read.

Comment: This question seems programming language neutral and relevant in an OOP context. (I've updated the tags in consequence) and sufficiently clear to be answered. I therefore propose to reopen it.

Comment: @JonasH if this is so typical for learning OOP and if you have already spotted a potential issue, why close the question and not answer it? Could you please vote to reopen it?

Comment: Hello Yana,  I have replaced the C# tag with OOP since there is not a single reference to C# in your code and it seems more a general OOP question.  Someone removed the UML tag, I put it back since obviously, this is an UML diagram.  If C# matters,  don't hesitate to replace the OOP tag back with C# and edit the question to clarify what specific C# issue you are trying to solve :-)

Comment: Meanwhile in short form some comments that I'd like to delvelop in an answer if your question gets reopened:  1) yes they can work together; 2) beware of multiplicity and the impacts of navigable association on this collaboration; 3) reconsider carefully if ingredients are really products on the menu (i.e. if cheese is on a pizza, are you sure, that you'll find a separate entry cheese with a unit price on the menu?) 4) If ingredients are products because you buy them,  consider that the price of a sold product (revenue) is not the same as the price of purchased products (cost)...

Comment: @Christophe It is not clear to me what the actual problem is. **Can** a object own another object that shares the same base class? sure, but that is rather trivial. Would it be **useful** to do so? For this example I have no idea, since there is no actual behavior presented, nor any background.

Comment: @JonasH Thanks for your reaction. Things that are trivial for us may be challenging for people new to OOP who seek help. “ingredient is a part”, “a list of ingredients”: OP sees the potential object composition (not necessarily UML composition);  “same properties”: OP wants inheritance for reuse, and wonders if both are possible at the same time.  The question seems legitimate,  considering that composition and inheritance are often opposed in so many posts.

Comment: @Christophe yes thank you, it is not specifically c# based, so the tag should not have been there. And also thank you for some explanation, it made things much more clear for me, I was afraid that I asked a wrong question here, but it seems like it is something others can learn from too. I'm not too sure who closed the question, but I consider it solved, thank you all.

Comment: @Yana_dublex good news:  the question was reopened (which is very rare, but as you said,  there is potential for others to learn as well from it).  So I developed the arguments of my comment :-)

Comment: @Yana_dublex: If you consider your question solved by the answer of Christophe, then you should formally ACCEPT his answer as the correct one by clicking on the ✓ (tick/checkmark) button which you can find underneath the answer's score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, they can!

Yes, classes that inherit from the same super-class can perfectly work together. There is no incompatibility.  There is even a design pattern that uses both relations on the same classes (the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)).

Remark:  The wording "*Working together*" is somewhat ambiguous and could mean different things.  But your class-diagram is precise enough and shows that you mean a possible association.

### But how?

Your diagram shows a navigable association between `Pizza` and `Ingredient` (the open arrow).  This means that the implementation shall make sure that a pizza can easily find its ingredients.

In your narrative you mention a list. I understand that an `Ingredient` can exist without any Pizza, but a Pizza can have several `Ingredient`.  It is important to specify this multiplicity on the diagram, by indicating  `*`  on the `Ingredient` side of the association.

The relationship in the opposite direction has still some mysteries:

- Navigability is unspecified:  we don't know if an `Ingredient` shall be able to easily find the related pizza or if this is not relevant.  You may specify this further with an arrow-head in the opposite direction (navigable) or with an X across the line (non-navigable).  You have the right to leave this unspecified and decide later.  The navigability has an impact on the way the classes can work together:  it means that `Pizza` can "work with" ingredient (e.g. use it as parameter in an operation, invoke an ingredient operation directly, etc...).  But the absence of navigability in the opposite direction would mean that `Ingredient` could not by itself  initiate a collaboration with its pizza.
- More important, the multiplicity:  we do not know if an ingredient is associated only with one pizza (`0..1`),  or if it can be shared between several (`0..*`). This is very important to know because the implementation would be very different (in the latter case you'd have a many-to-many association).

### Overgeneralization ?

Inheritance is tempting when one discovers OOP.  However,  inheritance has a lot of implications, constraints and consequences.  Therefore, use it wisely.

A useful advice is to start considering that A inherits from B, only if A is a more specialized B,  or conversely, that B is a more generalization of A.  It is dangerous to use inheritance just because some properties or operations share the same name. Names can by the way be misleading.

In your case, I understand a `Product` as something that the company sells at a given price: `Drink`, `Pizza`,  maybe `Antipasti` or `Pasta`. The price indicated, is the price requested from the customer.  I therefore wonder if an `Ingredient` is sold to the customer. AN ingredient may have a price, but it is a purchase price.  A purchase price is different from a sales price:   imagine that a restaurant would subcontract some very special pizza: the sales price would be different from the purchasing price.

Of course, if your `Product` is something more general, in the business meaning, and if it can have a sales price and a purchase price, and is not necessarily on the menu, then no problem, go-ahead.  But be aware that such generalized products are much more complex to manage (e.g. here a well-known [ERP example](https://www.guru99.com/material-master-views-ultimate-guide-2.html) with more than 20 different screens to manage all the aspects of a product).

### Other remarks

A very common advice is to [prefer composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). This rule of thumb aims to remind us to think twice before we use inheritance. Let's be clear, in case of doubt:  this does not mean that inheritance and composition are incompatible.

Comment: Just a philosophical question: should the multiplicity for `Ingredient` be rather `2..*`? `*` solely means any including none. Well, a pizza with no ingredients is definitely not a pizza. But even with one, it's just the ingredient, isn't it? So the minimum should be `2` to make it something new, right?

Comment: Right before you complete your reply :-) it's funny how modeling starts phantasy!

Comment: @qwerty_so That’s indeed a very relevant question. If you count the crust and considering that the crust alone is not very tasty, we could extrapolate that 2 is a bare minimum. My favorite pizzaiolo makes his crust himself with at least 3 ingredients which makes the pizza composed of at least 4. But if you want to support subcontracting (or worse, decongelation), a pizza could be made of a single ingredient.  Now, to support creativity, you must accept that the chief just invented a new pizza that can be sold this evening only, but the administrative clerk could not yet enter the receipe.(1/2)

Comment: @qwerty_so so to support this flexible business model (yes, not very industrial, but so tasteful and full of surprise) you’d need to accept a zero ingredients ad minimum, aknowledging that it may be temporary, or definitive if the next day the chief decided this was not the summum of culinary art she expected and decides to try yet another new special receipe). I love this kind of philosophic questions. (2/2)

Comment: The basis for each pizza is the dough which itself is made from water, olive oil, yeast, salt and flour (I make that each saturday). Of course one could buy an ready dough making it 1 ingredient, but I won't. And also a (frozen) pizza as a single "ingredient" is off limits!

Comment: @qwerty_so Aha !  I see that you have a much deeper coocking expertise than myself (and same for your UML expertise) ;-)  I ignored that olive oil was involved already at this early stage.  I can go to bed alittle more knowledgeable than the day before :-)

Comment: You can make it without. But fat transports taste and it makes the dough easier to work with. But of course this is no cooking tutorial here ;-) and I wouldn't be so sure about who has the most UML skill here...